# Prediction In Generalized Linear Models and Factorized Conditional Expectation

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, conditional-expectation

I have been introduced to generalized linear models as follows: Let there be sample data $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^p$ of the r.v. $\mathcal{X}$ organized as rows into the matrix $X$, and $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ a sample of the r.v. $\mathcal{Y}$, and consider as the statistical model for the distribution of $n$ independent copies of $\mathcal{Y}$ an exponential family $$f(y|\theta) = \exp\left(\frac{\theta^t y - b(\theta)}{\phi} - c(y,\phi)\right),\quad \theta\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
parametrized by $\theta$ that, via $\theta = X\beta$, is actually parametrized by $\beta$:
$$f(y|\beta) = \exp\left(\frac{(X\beta)^t y - b(X\beta)}{\phi} - c(y,\phi)\right),\quad \beta\in\mathbb{R}^p.$$

Solve the latter statistical model for the ML-estimator $\hat{\beta}$ and use it to predict $y$ given new data $x$ like so: $x\mapsto \hat{y}_x=\nabla b(x^t\hat{\beta})$.

What is the mathematical justification for the prediction to work? Working strictly with the statements of MLE-theory I find that the best prediction for $y$ is just always $E_{\hat{\beta}}\mathcal{Y} = \nabla b(X\hat{\beta})$ and that taking new data points $x$ into account would mean an updated $\hat{\beta}$ because all the theorems on MLE-theory I have seen do not include a functional component that I could plug $X$ into.
Right now, to me, $X$ is but a fixed part of the structural assumption of the statistical model.

What I suspect is that the statistical model should actually be written with densities $f(y|\beta, X)$, and that there is a theorem that links the functional dependence of the minimizer of $\beta\mapsto f(y|\beta, X)$ on $X$ to the factorized conditional expectation $E(\mathcal{Y}|\mathcal{X} = x)$ (which is the function $g$ that satisfies $E(\mathcal{Y}|\mathcal{X}) = g(\mathcal{X})$) in an approximate way that in particular makes the specification of the statistical model for $\mathcal{X}$ unnecessary.

Is there a theory in the context of these considerations and where can I find it? It shouldn't be particular to generalized linear models...